# What is the poetry of mathematics?

Tags: math-history

In computer science it's often noted, said or agreed on that algorithms are the poetry of computer science. What is considered the poetry of mathematics? Is it statistics? If there is something agreed on of course, like from a famous quote of a mathematician or so.

Comment: Mathematics is beautiful in itself and needs no sub-class of especial beauty. Statistics if anything is the dubious step-child.

Comment: Mathematics is the poetry of mathematics.

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder, but I'd say usually (abstract) algebra.

Comment: @SimonS I'm not a native speaker. What do you mean by dubious step-child?

Comment: I mean we (mathematicians) admit that statistics is a close relative. But it isn't strictly of our lineage and often doesn't reflect our best traits. Anyway, see Bertrand Russell quote below.

Comment: I don't believe that there is any recognized "poetry of mathematics" in the metaphorical sense you seem to be asking about.  Of course mathematicians quote and compose poetry from time to time, but this is a literal sense of "poetry".

Comment: @simon s I hope my step father has a better opinion of me than that. I understand your opinion but respectfully ask you to use a different  analogy

Comment: I did qualify it with **dubious**. From *Oxford English Dictionary*, definition 1.c: "Of questionable character: suspect, untrustworthy"

Comment: To be clear I understand the point being made. I happen to believe abstract algebra is the most poetic myself. I just think the comparison to step children dubious or not is unnecessary and may offend some.

Comment: Groan. "Dubious cousin" then. I do hope my cousins aren't reading this and write me angry emails saying how they thought I always loved them and are now shocked, *shocked*, to discover that in using the term "dubious cousin" in a figurative sense--on a thread about poetic sensibility no less!--makes them think I literally have a lesser opinion of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Proofs are the poetry of mathematics. Even the most simple proofs are beautiful.

Proof: $0a = 0$ $$0a = (1-1)a = a - a = 0$$

Proof: The number of primes is infinite.

Assume that the number is finite. Suppose that $p_1=2 < p_2 = 3 < ... < p_r$ are all of the primes. Let $P = p_1p_2...p_r+1$ and let p be a prime dividing P; then p can not be any of $p_1, p_2, ..., p_r$, otherwise p would divide the difference $P-p_1p_2...p_r=1$, which is impossible. So this prime p is still another prime, and $p_1, p_2, ..., p_r$ would not be all of the primes.

Proofs are beautiful. Based on a few axioms, we can describe wonders.

Comment: I'm pretty sure $P_n+1$ has $2$ as a factor

Comment: "$P_n+1$ has no prime factors"... unless $P_n=2$, we must have $2\mid P_n+1$...

Comment: Totally agree with this

Comment: @Alessandro I edited the proof.

Comment: @abiessu I edited the proof

Comment: wonderful proof that 0a = 0 :) I remember how we proven this in class on first or second math lesson. It was awesome:)

Answer (score 5):

> Mathematics, rightly viewed, possesses not only truth, but supreme beauty — a beauty cold and austere, like that of sculpture, without appeal to any part of our weaker nature, without the gorgeous trappings of painting or music, yet sublimely pure, and capable of a stern perfection such as only the greatest art can show. The true spirit of delight, the exaltation, the sense of being more than Man, which is the touchstone of the highest excellence, is to be found in mathematics as surely as poetry.

-- Bertrand Russell, "The Study of Mathematics" (1919)

Comment: I was about to look up this quote in response to this question. I think some of the best statements about the beauty of mathematics comes from mathematicians of the early 20th century such as Russell, Hardy, Hilbert, and others.